# Java FTP Download speed

Tags: java, performance, ftp

I try to download files from a specific directory on a free ftp. While using Filezilla it goes quickly, but with my java program its painfully slow and don't know why. I tried to increase the Buffersize without results. I am really clueless,does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot

```
private void DLAll() {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {           
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        boolean login=ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();            
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024000); 
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteDIR);
        FTPFile[] files=ftpClient.listFiles();           

        if(files != null && files.length >0)
        {
            number_file=files.length;
            loop_index=0;
            for(FTPFile fl:files)
            {
                if(loop_index<pLimit) 
                  {
                    if(!fl.isFile())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Accessing:" + fl.getName());

                    //Download only zip files
                    if (fl.getName().endsWith("zip"))
                       {
                                // APPROACH #2: using InputStream retrieveFileStream(String)
                                String remoteFile2 = remoteDIR+"/"+fl.getName();
                                File downloadFile2 = new File(localDIR+fl.getName());
                                OutputStream outputStream2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile2));
                                ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
                                InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile2);
                                byte[] bytesArray = new byte[1024*1024];
                                int bytesRead = 0;
                                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
                                    outputStream2.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
                                }

                                boolean success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
                                if (success) {
                                    System.out.println("File "+fl.getName()+" has been downloaded successfully." + ftpClient.getBufferSize());
                                }
                                outputStream2.close();
                                inputStream.close();
                                loop_index++; 
                            }   
                       }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("skipping:" + fl.getName());
                    }
                 }  
            }
        } 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();}
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do any profiling?

Comment: No, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution was strangely to invert Outputstream.Close() and . Close first, then let the command run.I have no idea why. I found the solution here: https://coderanch.com/t/422797/java/InputStream-org-apache-commons-net

```
                                outputStream2.close();
                                inputStream.close();
                                loop_index++;  

                                boolean success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
                                if (success) {
                                    long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                                    System.out.println("File "+fl.getName()+" has been downloaded successfully in " + estimatedTime + "; Buffer:" + buffer_size);
                               }
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you check the delay for downloading a single file for various buffer sizes? If it is the same then you probably need to implement the multiple downloads by using multithreading (which filezilla surely does). Try using java 8 parallel stream on the FtpEntries for quick implementation.

Comment: How can I do this ? I am really new to java

Comment: Stream.of(files).parallel().forEach(file->{ //add your download code here})